# How to add text fields to a user uploaded PDF by drag and drop method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, docusignapi, adobe-sign

please someone explain me to how to drag and drop a text field to the uploaded PDF like adobe sign do.

I'm trying to make a react application using DocuSign API, I need to add fields in the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use embedded sending to embed the sending experience in your app which then allows your users to drag and drop tabs on the document. This [how-to guide](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embedded-sending/) provides sample code that shows how to use this feature. You can also download a [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) and run the embedded sending example to see how this works.

Comment: I have another question..
After creating envelope, user will be redirected to `https://appdemo.docusign.com/prepare/${response.data.envelopeId}/add-fields...
When user landing on this link, it asks the user to login.
How to make that link without asks login?

Comment: I believe that you can only use the embedded sending experience if the user logs in because only authenticated users can send envelopes. Embedded signing is different because the signer does not need to log in but if you want the user to be able to edit the envelope they need to log in.

Comment: Thanks for your response.... Then how to get all signed documents in my application?

Comment: You might be able to use the Envelopes:listStatus endpoint for that. Just look for envelopes with the status "completed." https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatus/

Comment: Can we list out these documents in our app?

Comment: Yes you can list documents for the completed envelopes as shown in this how-to. https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/list-envelope-documents/